# Handle unknown entity input on dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Assume you want to create an intent to order the pizza and the user has to choose what kind of pizza he wants. In order to recognise what pizza the user wants you create an entity pizza with the entries:

diavola, prosciutto and hawaii

How do you handle the situation if a user specifies a pizza which does not exist in the pizza entity? Currently you could use prompts of "action and parameters" to tell the user that his choice was not valid. However, if the user has not chosen a pizza type at all he will be prompted with the same sentence, which does not makes sense in this scenario.

Example 1:

> User: I want to order a pizza funghi
>
> Bot: I do not understand your choice.

Example 2:

> User: I want to order a pizza
>
> Bot: I do not understand your choice.

In the latter example you would want to the bot to say: What kind of pizza do you like?

**Details:**

Training phrase: I want to order pizza [diavola] -> entity_pizza

Action and parameters: parameter entity_pizza is required and prompt = "I do not understand your choice"

Comment: Have you tried adding another intent to handle your second example? The bot will otherwise not be able to distinguish between them and respond separately.

Comment: Hm, interesting idea as a workaround. I will check this.